# nestjs configure https.agent

Tags: https, nestjs

Hi I've tried to use nestJs framework to build a simple application.
This application call a http service to retrive and log some informations. I attach the code of nestjs service:

```
import { HttpService, Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { UserInformation } from 'src/models/userInformation';
import https from 'https';
@Injectable()
    export class CallService {
      private authRequest: any;
      private httpsAgent: https.Agent;
    
      constructor(
        private configService: ConfigService,
        private httpService: HttpService,
      ) {
        this.httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
          rejectUnauthorized: false,
        });
        this.authRequest = {
          username: configService.get('username'),
          password: configService.get('password'),
        };
      }
    
      getUserInformation(): Promise<UserInformation> {
        var url = this.configService.get('apiEndpoint') + 'scrapt/getUserInfo';
    
        return this.httpService
          .get(url, {
            auth: this.authRequest,
            httpsAgent: this.httpsAgent,
          })
          .toPromise()
          .then((response) => {
            return new UserInformation(response.data);
          });
      }
    
      }
```

when the

> getUserInformation

function is trigger in console appear this error:

> 'Cannot read property 'Agent' of undefined'

it is ref on line:

```
 this.httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
```

I tried to search some information on internet but I did not found anything have we any idea how resolve it?

Comment: nest can't resolve the value for this `https.Agent` type. I think reading about [custom providers](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers) or using the [http module](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module) instead will help out.

Answer (score 4):

try `import * as https from 'https'`

You can also check the [esModuleInterop](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/esModuleInterop.html) documentation

Comment: this actually solved my issue. as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

To get user agent import Request from express

```
import { Request } from 'express';
```

Then use it in your controller/service/middleware using the `Request` .
Controller example is given here.

```
@Get()
someMethodName(@Req() request: Request) {
   const userAgent = request.get('user-agent');
   console.log(userAgent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try making use of a dynamic module**

---

- /src

  - /httpsAgent

    - constants.ts
    - httpsAgent.module.ts
  - example.module.ts
  - example.service.ts

### /src/httpsAgent/constants.ts

Create a variable that is later imported, which is a nestjs recommendation.

```
export const HttpsAgentClient = 'HttpsAgentClient'
```

### /src/httpsAgent/httpsAgent.module.ts

Create a dynamic module that takes in three arguments for the path of the cert, key and ca.

```
import { DynamicModule, Module, Provider } from '@nestjs/common';
import https from 'https';
import fs from 'fs';
import { HttpsAgentClient } from './constants';

@Module({})
export class HttpsAgentModule {
    static forRoot(certPath: string, keyPath: string, caPath: string): DynamicModule {

        const httpsAgentProvider: Provider = {
            provide: HttpsAgentClient,
            useFactory: () => {
                return new https.Agent({
                    cert: fs.readFileSync(certPath, { encoding: 'utf8' }),
                    key: fs.readFileSync(keyPath, { encoding: 'utf8' }),
                    ca: fs.readFileSync(caPath, { encoding: 'utf8' }),
                });
            }
        };
            
        return {
            module: HttpsAgentModule,
            providers: [httpsAgentProvider],
            exports: [httpsAgentProvider]
        };
    }
}
```

### /src/example.module.ts

Import the dynamic module into your target module.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ExampleController } from './example.controller';
import { ExampleService } from './example.service';
import { HttpsAgentModule } from './httpsAgent/httpsAgent.module';

@Module({
    controllers: [ExampleController],
    providers: [ExampleService],
    imports: [
        HttpsAgentModule.forRoot(
            './ssl/certPath.pem',
            './ssl/keyPath.key',
            './ssl/caPath.pem'
        )
    ]
})
export class ExampleModule {}
```

### /src/example.service.ts

Inject your dynamic module into the target service file.

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpsAgentClient } from './httpsAgent/constants';
    
@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {
    constructor(
        @Inject(HttpsAgentClient)
        private readonly httpsAgent: object,
    ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's suitable, it's possible to define the option `rejectUnauthorized` within the module import:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';
import * as https from 'https';

@Module({
  imports: [
    HttpModule.register({
      httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      }),
    }),
  ],
  // ...
})
export class MyModule {}
```