# Use RESTful API with and without JWT authentication

Tags: javascript, rest, backend, nestjs, middleware

I have a web application with Angular front-end and a back-end developed using the Nest.JS framework.

The back-end RESTful API endpoints are secured with an SSO and JWT authentication.

Using the same web application I created a desktop application with the help of the NW.JS.
The application setup is successful and can run on the desktop OS.

Now I need to use the same back-end RESTful API endpoints without the SSO but with JWT for the desktop application.

In some situations (ex. checking for updates), I only need to use the SSO login.

How can I use the Nest.JS server endpoints for this kind of use cases.

Is there a conditional way to write annotations/middleware that we can use to check the app is running on WEB or Desktop and bypass the SSO login?

Also this should be a much secure way to protect the endpoint in both situations.

NOTE: Identifying the running environment is also has configured and running well in the application.

Thank you very much

Comment: *Is there a conditional way to write annotations/middleware that we can use to check the app is running on WEB or Desktop and bypass the SSO login?* **use a header, different endpoint URL or a URL query string**

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Is there any example with what your talking of in the nest.js documentation?

if available it is also be a good help.

Also I see the API versioning, is it also good to use for this purpose? 
link - (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/versioning)

Comment: User agent can help you to find that the request is coming from desktop / web. Then based on that you can enable / disable JWT check. If you want to know how to use user agent then check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66313609/nestjs-configure-https-agent/69722963#69722963

Comment: Thank you for the comment. This will be a good solution for the application. Would there be any security vulnerabilities by doing so?